# Cannot format my USB Flash Drive after installing Vanilla Chrome OS

Tags: usb-flash-drive, formatting, google-chrome-os

I recently installed Chromium OS ([Hexxeh's vanilla build](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/)) on my 16 GB flash drive.

Later on, when I tried to format it, it was showing a total space of 1 GB. I tried deleting partitions in disk management, but I was only able to delete some of them. It was then showing free space of 16 MB.

For one partition, when I tried to format it, I got the following error:

---

[image: error message]

> An unexpected error has occurred. Check the System Event Log for more
>   information on the error. Close the Disk Management console, then
>   restart Disk Management or restart the computer.

---

The following images show the partitions that I cannot delete:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What can I do to reclaim the full space of my flash drive?

Comment: Can you tell me the Brand of you penDrive..?

Comment: HP flash drive!

Answer (score 18):

The disk most likely needs to be cleaned. Use the command line utility 'diskpart' to simply just wipe clean the entire device.

DISCLAIMER:

> It is recommended that you use the Diskpart utility cautiously because Diskpart enables explicit control of partitions and volumes.

From Run: diskpart

[image: RunDiskpart]

[image: DiskPart]

```
1.list disk
```

**Pay Attention Here** What disk do you want to clean?

```
2.select disk #
```

Replace # with the disk you're **100% sure** you want to clean.

```
3.clean
4.create partition primary
5.select partition 1
6.active
7.format quick fs=fat32
8.assign
9.exit
```

See MS article here for more info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: on step 4 i get this error,                No usable free extent could be found. It may be that there is insufficient
free space to create a partition at the specified size and offset. Specify
different size and offset values or don't specify either to create the
maximum sized partition. It may be that the disk is partitioned using the MBR disk
partitioning format and the disk contains either 4 primary partitions, (no
more partitions may be created), or 3 primary partitions and one extended
partition, (only logical drives may be created).

Answer (score 2):

I ususally solve those strange situations with usb dongles with the

```
HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool
```

you can find it on Google

Comment: Thanks, this registry trick solved the problem.Anyways thanks for the answer.!! http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/usb-flash-drive-prompts-with-write-protected/2012d40c-7d90-4967-b2c2-2d67c08561e2

Answer (score -2):

Download Rufus and click on "FreeDOS", then it will wipeout and then format it the normal way to make it working as usual. - LordXuran